# How to rotate bounding box x,y,w,h format rectangle for a given rotation angle say -90 degrees in an image using python?

Tags: python, math, geometry, bounding-box

I have got a rectangle with x_90,y_90,w_90,h_90 = 2212,642,30,90 respectively. 90 degree rotated image height,width = 2339,1654

Now I need to rotate based on the orientation angle detected. In this case, it is 90 degrees hence, it needs to be rotated by -90 degrees. This should result in the rotated point as  x_0,y_0,w_0,h_0 = 642,95,90,30 respectively in the image. 0 degree rotated image or original image height,width = 1654,2339 .

I Am unable to rotate since I don't know how to do it in this case since the origin of the image starts from the top-left corner of the page

Comment: rotate_image = cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)

Comment: draw a sketch on a piece of graph paper or something. make up some values for your points, note the points and their values in the sketch. now turn the sketch. can you figure out what the coordinates of your points should be now? it's just addition and subtraction